# Python - Erro import pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Pessoal estou com problemas quando tento usar o pandas no meu projeto, vejam esse erro:

```
File "c:\Users\jua2544825\Desktop\front_reembolso\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas import read_csv as pd
  File "C:\Users\jua2544825\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
dateutil: No module named 'dateutil'
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar ocasionando esse erro?
fiz a instalação do pandas normalmente, testei em outra maquina minha e funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você fez a instalação utilizando o pip?

```
pip3 install python-dateutil
```

Comment: FIz esse comando e funcionou, muito obrigado pela força :D